# why does google maps code wrapped in a div not work?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

This is a simple code to display google maps. There is a little more feature than that i.e it also allows creating a path when clicked on multiple points. Those extensions aren't relevant to the issue though. The issue i am facing is that the following code works. It displays the google maps correctly but the second code below which is the same code as the first but the body content wrapped with a div block. The second code doesn't work i.e it doesn't display the map. I am wondering why wrapping the body with div is breaking the google map display functionality. I appreciate any help! Thanks!

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>Simple Map</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <style>
         html, body {
         height: 100%;
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
         }
         #map {
         height: 100%;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>



     <div id="info">
        <label> Distance: </label>
        <label id="dis"> </label>
     </div>
     <div>
        <button onClick="reset()"> Reset </button>
        <button onClick="getLatLong()"> Save </button>
     </div>

      <div id="map"></div>
      <script>
         var map;

         var coordinates = [];

         function reset(){


         document.getElementById('dis').innerHTML = "";
         initMap();



         }

         function getLatLong(){
         document.getElementById('dis').innerHTML = map.getCenter() + map.getZoom();
         }    

         function initMap() {


           map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
             center: {lat: 40.274330810357355, lng: -111.68475025794504},
             zoom: 17
           });


         var lineSymbol = {path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW};

         map.addListener('click', function( event ){

         coordinates.push({lat: event.latLng.lat(), lng: event.latLng.lng() });

         var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
         path: coordinates,
         icons: [{icon: lineSymbol, offset: '100%'}],
         geodesic: true,
         strokeColor: '#FF0000',
         strokeOpacity: 1.0,
         strokeWeight: 2
         });

         flightPath.setMap(map);



         });

         }


      </script>
      <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=keykey&callback=initMap"
         async defer></script>




   </body>
</html>
```

If i wrap the body content with a div then the map doesnt display.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>Simple Map</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <style>
         html, body {
         height: 100%;
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
         }
         #map {
         height: 100%;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>

    **<div>**


     <div id="info">
        <label> Distance: </label>
        <label id="dis"> </label>
     </div>
     <div>
        <button onClick="reset()"> Reset </button>
        <button onClick="getLatLong()"> Save </button>
     </div>

      <div id="map"></div>
      <script>
         var map;

         var coordinates = [];

         function reset(){


         document.getElementById('dis').innerHTML = "";
         initMap();



         }

         function getLatLong(){
         document.getElementById('dis').innerHTML = map.getCenter() + map.getZoom();
         }    

         function initMap() {


           map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
             center: {lat: 40.274330810357355, lng: -111.68475025794504},
             zoom: 17
           });


         var lineSymbol = {path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW};

         map.addListener('click', function( event ){

         coordinates.push({lat: event.latLng.lat(), lng: event.latLng.lng() });

         var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
         path: coordinates,
         icons: [{icon: lineSymbol, offset: '100%'}],
         geodesic: true,
         strokeColor: '#FF0000',
         strokeOpacity: 1.0,
         strokeWeight: 2
         });

         flightPath.setMap(map);



         });

         }


      </script>
      <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=keykey&callback=initMap"
         async defer></script>


    **</div>**


   </body>
</html>
```

UPDATE:

After adding the following css,

```
#map {
  position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
}
```

the map occupies the whole page. I just want to encapsulate the map into a div.

[image]

Comment: why is this question voted down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i am posting answer to my problem. So, it seems no matter how much deep is the map container if you set the div height and width to certain pixels then the map will appear in that space. This is what i wanted so the solution was

```
#map {
         height: 500px;
         width: 500px;
    }
```

Comment: Which is exactly the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

you can try something like this

```
#map {
  position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
}
```

This way you don't have to set the height of the parent div.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried the css and it looks as shown above in UPDATE section. I want the map to be encapsulated in a div rather than occupy the whole page. Thanks!

Comment: All you need to do is define `#map` to the size/location you want - and the map code will render the map into the element.  You don't need to wrap the JS in a div to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

`map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map')`

identifies the HTML element the map will be rendered into.  If you want the map to be less than full screen. just give`#map` some CSS to define its size and  location.  There is no need to wrap the JS in a div to achieve this.  For example:

```
#map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  right: 0;
  width:400px;
  height:400px
}
```

This will give you a 400px square map in the top right corner of the window

Comment: map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map') is not enough. If the map div is inside another div then the map is not rendered. The problem i am facing is that i cannot remove the outer div. I will need to make the map appear in the inner div without removing the outer div.

Answer (score -1):

wait for the page to load completely before runing JS scripts. If you're using jquery `$(document).ready(function(){  /** your js code **/ });`

Comment: can you offer a full solution? in the above code it seems the initMap() is called by the google maps library since the call is specified as part of a callback.

Comment: try adding an onload in your body tag `<body onload="initMap();">`

Comment: it looks like i need to set the height and width of parent div but the problem is i have a layout in grails application that applies to all view pages and the layout has a div container for bootstrap <div class="base-container">. The layout body is inside this div so i dont think it is good idea to set the width and height of the base container for just one view page. i appreciate any solution to this predicament. Thanks!

Comment: @user734861 great! i think gmap requires px width and height. percent doesn't work on it.